# Validations for excluded dates.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My Code works. The problem I have here is that dates like November 31 and April 31 can occur every year from 2010 down to 1995 which means I have to type in all these dates e.g [Date.new(2012,09,31),Date.new(2011,09,31)] and so on. I am trying to make this validation work for only the month and the day to avoid too much typing or in other words shorten my code please see a description of my 
Model/profile.rb

```
 validate :excluded_dates

private
def excluded_dates
exclusion_dates = [Date.new(2012,9,31), Date.new(2012,2,1)]
if exclusion_dates.include?(self.next_shoeing)
  self.errors.add(:next_shoeing, "cannot be on a reserved date.")
end
```

Comment: How many excluded dates do you plan to have? And is there any pattern in these excluded dates?

Comment: I plan to exclude dates that dont exist such as November31 April 31 and Sept 31st and I am trying to this for all my date columns

Answer (score 1):

First of all doing `Date.new(2012,9,31)` will throw you an `ArgumentError: invalid date`. IMO there is no need to validate this as no one will be able to construct such date (just handling this exception outside this model).

So if `next_shoeing` is an instance of `Date` it won't be invalid anyway.